# Github clone a previous configuration

Tags: git, reset

I am a git novice, and can't really understand the answers to similar questions.  Sorry. I made a bad mistake many months ago and need to fetch a previous version and make it the current one. Since I couldn't figure out how to do this elegantly, I did it by brute force - downloading a zip file with the version I wanted then unzipping it and using commit and push to make it the latest version. If SHA is the identity of the version I want to "promote", exactly what is the git CLI command to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

After cloning your repo, go to that directory and check SHA id from git log:

Try:

```
git log
```

Then:

```
# Resets index to former commit; replace '<commit_id>' with your commit code
git reset <commit_id>

# Moves pointer back to previous HEAD
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}

git commit -m "Revert to <commit_id>"

# Updates working copy to reflect the new commit
git reset --hard
```

For more info, visit this link:
[How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: I just put a comment on Answer 0, but it seems this does exactly what I wanted, bringing the last good file to the top, and leaving the rest of the "stack" alone - is that right?

Comment: yeah, it is. @dms489.
FYI, you can also start a new branch leaving the old one untouched by doing, `git checkout -b <new branch name> <commit_id>`. And do what ever you want to do with `<new branch name>`

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `git log` to get the SHA-1 hash of the commit you want to fetch.
2. `git reset --hard [your_commit_hash]`
3. `git push --force`

**Warning:** this will **completely erase** all the commits you made since the commit you `git reset` to!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I don't mind losing all the intermediate versions, but would like to keep the latest in the bad series of events for reference.  So I have 2 SHAs - SHA last_good and SHA_latest_bad. When I finish I'd like to have SHA_last_good on the top of the "stack" and SHA_latest_bad beneath it.  Is that possible?

Comment: In this case, you can use `git reset` and `git push --force` to restore the latest bad commit and then commit again your latest good commit using your brute force method.

Comment: You can save the bad commit history by putting a branch there. Intuitively, that's probably what you want to do anyway.